# How do I test associations in Rails when I'm using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I have a rails 4 project that uses Mongo. I'm trying to run unit tests and feature tests. Both are having errors running the test.

Unit Tests:
I tried using regular shoulda matchers to test associations and validations. The validations worked but not the associations. I got this:

```
Failures:

1) Image 
 Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:user) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Image_2:0x007fde82448d70 @__memoized=nil>
 # ./spec/models/image_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So I did some research and decided that the problem was that Mongo does not use active record so I could not test associations with a gem that uses active record. So installed a gem called : 'mongoid-rspec'

Now I get the following error:

```
rspec spec/features/user_can_create_account_and_login.rb
/Users/dmitryjum/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- mongoid/associations (LoadError)
```

And the tests don't run at all. I get the same problem in my feature tests. What should I do?

Comment: try to update gem "mongoid" and gem "mongoid-rspec" 
check this links it will use for you
https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec/issues/21
https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec/issues/22

Answer (score 1):

Use [mongoid-rspec](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-rspec), it adds a lot of matchers like

```
RSpec.describe Article do
  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:author).of_type(User).as_inverse_of(:articles) }
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The proper name for the association is "belongs_to", not "belong_to" which is a typo.

What are the relevant lines for Rails and Mongoid in Gemfile, and in Gemfile.lock after running bundle install?

For Rails 4, you should specify Mongoid 4 which is in beta with the following, see https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid/versions/4.0.0.beta1

Gemfile

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
```